# Attribute value not changing in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, class

This is my apex class:
Here i have used custom setting object and field.

```
public with sharing class sample{
public sample(Assetcommunication_Max controller) {}
public string settings{get;set;}
public string vars{get;set;}
Public sample(){
FileFilter__c settings = FileFilter__c.getvalues('Filterextension');
system.debug('name is'+settings.FileType__c);
vars = settings.FileType__c;
  }
}
```

This is my visualforce code:

```
 <apex:inputFile value="{!file.versionData}" accept="{!vars}"  fileName="{!file.pathOnClient}" styleClass="slds-button--brand"  onchange="showbutton()" />
```

In the **accept attribute** value is not retrieving/accepting from apex class.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code , it was working.

```
public sample(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
}
public string getAcceptFileNames()
{
    FileFilter__c settings = FileFilter__c.getvalues('Filterextension');
    system.debug('name is'+settings.FileType__c);
    string AcceptFileNames = settings.FileType__c;
    return AcceptFileNames;
}
```

visualforce code:

`<apex:inputFile value="{!file.versionData}"  accept="{!AcceptFileNames}"  fileName="{!file.pathOnClient}" styleClass="slds-button--brand"  onchange="showbutton()" />`